# MO theory methods other than LCAO

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

What methods other than linear combination of atomic orbitals does MO theory use? Which one is the most accurate and comprehensive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this gets into the concept of [basis sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_set_(chemistry)).

[LCAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination_of_atomic_orbitals) implies that the number of molecular orbitals will be the same as the number of atomic orbitals involved.

In fact, we usually use ***more*** basis functions than just the simple number of atomic orbitals. We might add diffuse or polarization functions to better describe electron density away from the nucleus.

Moreover, rather than the physically correct [Slater-type orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_orbitals):

$$R_l(r) = A(l,\alpha) r^l e^{-\alpha r}$$

We usually use [Gaussian-type orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_orbital) to express the radial component.

$$R_l(r) = B(l,\alpha) r^l e^{-\alpha r^2}$$

Now GTOs don't express the radial part of the wave function well -- they decay too quickly as you get far from the nucleus. So we use a linear combination of multiple Gaussian orbitals to approximate the physically-correct Slater terms. Still, it's much faster to use a set of multiple GTOs.

Beyond STOs and GTOs, people do use other types of orbitals. For example:

- [Wavelets](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4853)
- [Plane waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_set_(chemistry)#Plane-wave_basis_sets)
- [Muffin-tin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muffin-tin_approximation)